# Web extension development in safari with JS framework

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, web-extension

I'm looking for a way to develop a safari web extension with any JS frameworks like AngularJS / ReactJS. Can someone help me to understand if it's possible, or can it be done only with plain JS? Is there any official safari documentation on this subject?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use React in a Safari web extension - they are very similar to web extensions for Chrome and Firefox, so most documentation for those will also apply here.

Here's a great blog post about the quirks of developing Safari web extensions on iOS, including the use of React and Typescript: https://www.bedelstein.com/post/building-a-safari-app-extension-in-ios-15